# java lang NumberFormatException

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am trying to convert string to double. But i am getting the number format exception. The code that gives the exception is like this:

```
double B = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

I take the s value from server to my application. And it is like this:

```
fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f
```

Any solution?

Comment: `fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f` is the number in which base?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I guess hex... As there is no dot or comma, I guess it is an integer number (not `int` though, much too high)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (i am assuming the string is HEX coz of the 0-9 & a-f in it)

```
double doubleVal = new BigInteger("fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f", 16).longValue();
long longVal = new BigInteger("fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f", 16).longValue();
System.out.println(doubleVal);
System.out.println(longVal);
```

This gives:

```
8.4848548707027374E18
8484854870702737183
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** `Double.parseDouble()` works only on `Double` **Numbers** , **Not** on `non-Numbers`.

**2.** `fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f` is **NO Number**......

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble(s)` is doing just fine if `s` is number. Apparently you are receiving the number in hex base. Right?

It's simple as this:

```
double doubleAsLongReverse = new BigInteger(doubleAsString, 16).longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double B = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Which is works  only for numbers not for such fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f values example
`String s = "123";
        double B = Double.parseDouble(s);
        System.out.println(B);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Hex`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) in Apache's Commons Codec.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ByteBuffer class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html
You can put bytes from string s.getBytes() and then call getDouble()

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
double doubleVal = new BigInteger("fd485b154a0427fa75c0428cdafac71f", 16).doubleValue();
System.out.println(doubleVal);
```

prints

```
3.366703756933705E38
```

If you use .longValue() you will be chopping off the start of the number due to an overflow.